# How to get the camera matrix of a camera sensor in Ignition Gazebo

Tags: gazebo-ignition

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have a world in Ignition Gazebo that contains a camera and a robot arm (panda). The camera has the robot in view. I would like to compute the pixel position of the robot's end-effector within the recorded camera image.

What I would like to know is how/where to find the camera matrix (and information about distortion if applicable) so that I can compute the projection.

I can find the projected position of the end-effector in the camera's frame of reference, but to convert the location into pixels I need the camera's intrinsic parameters. I thought they would be published on the /camera_info topic, but the simulator doesn't appear to publish any messages on this topic. My next thought was to check the camera sensor's source code, but I can't seem to figure out where it is located.

Any pointers where to find this information are highly appreciated :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/26690/how-to-get-the-camera-matrix-of-a-camera-sensor-in-ignition-gazebo/) by [FirefoxMetzger](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/44219/firefoxmetzger/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It is indeed possible to get the camera matrix from the `/camera_info` topic. It also directly provides a projection matrix to map between pixel coordinates and meters.

However, there is a gotcha that is not so obvious: Gazebo doesn't follow the typical convention of defining the camera's coordinate system with the z-axis pointing forward. Instead, it follows the default robotics joint convention and **cameras have the x-axis pointing forward** (z-axis pointing up). The projection matrix, however, is given in a format that assumes the standard camera coordinate frame (z-axis pointing forward, y-axis pointing down). As a result, an additional transformation (rotation) is needed to convert the position, before applying the projection.

Here is the critical piece of code in python to (hopefully) make things more clear:

```
def world2px_cam_info(pos_world):
    # camera info msg based projection

    ## pos in world coords -> pos in camera coords
    # gazebo doesn't use conventional camera coordinates
    # camera points in x-direction instead of z-direction
    tf = transform(np.array((0,0,0, np.pi/2, np.pi/2, 0)))
    pos_cam_gazebo = homogenize(world2cam(pos_world))
    pos_cam = np.matmul(tf, pos_cam_gazebo)

    projection = np.array(cam_info.projection.p).reshape((3, 4))
    pos_px = cartesianize(np.matmul(projection, pos_cam))

    #image indexing uses y-x order instead of x-y
    pos_px = pos_px[::1]

    return pos_px
```

I've added a full code example below (using `gym-ignition` and [ropy](https://github.com/FirefoxMetzger/ropy)). It produces the following image:

[image: Projection]

https://gist.github.com/FirefoxMetzger/dc9af8ae62fce176a3fe037d095988dc

Edit: The .sdf was causing problems because it contained absolute paths for my local file system due to the traffic cone. I updated the .sdf, moved the code into a gist for syntax highlighting, and added [ropy](https://github.com/FirefoxMetzger/ropy) which takes care of the additional rotation and makes the code cleaner overall.

---

Originally posted by [FirefoxMetzger](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/44219/firefoxmetzger/) with karma: 1 on 2021-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndrejOrsula](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/44778/andrejorsula/) on 2021-03-19**:
Great that you made it work, good job! To have camera with "standard camera coordinate frame", you can also set the link or sensor pose (`relative_to` requires SDF 1.7).

```
<model name="camera_model">
  <pose>0 0 10 0 3.14 0</pose>
  <link name="sensor_link">
    <sensor name="camera_sensor" type="camera">
      <pose relative_to="camera_model::sensor_link">0 0 0 -1.57 -1.57 -1.57</pose>
      <!-- ... -->
    </sensor>
    <!-- ... -->
  </link>
</model>
```

**Comment by [FirefoxMetzger](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/44219/firefoxmetzger/) on 2021-03-20**:
@AndrejOrsula Thanks! I would upvote your comment because it is really useful; unfortunately, it requires 3 rep to do so, meaning I will have to wait with that until somebody upvotes my question or answer :)

**Comment by [benedikt](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/88831/benedikt/) on 2022-06-03**:
This worked for me, but I'm having problems with using the camera_info topic in ROS2 Galactic with the camera sensor of type rgbd_camera. I've set up a ros_ign_bridge with the argument `/camera_info@sensor_msgs/msg/CameraInfo[ignition.msgs.CameraInfo` This forwards the the camera_info topic to ROS2 successfully. But changing the image width and/or height has no effect on the camera matrix of the camera_info topic. I had to explicitly set the `<intrinsics>` tag in the sdf. Is this normal or a bug?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Your intuition about `/camera_info` topic is correct. Can you try the following example to see if that works for you?

```
ign gazebo camera_sensor.sdf -r
ign topic -e -t /camera_info
```

You should see `ign_msgs.CameraInfo` messages printed to stdout.
In order to see more information about these messages, you can use `ign msg -i ign_msgs.CameraInfo`.

---

Originally posted by [AndrejOrsula](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/44778/andrejorsula/) with karma: 101 on 2021-03-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FirefoxMetzger](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/44219/firefoxmetzger/) on 2021-03-18**:
Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, I have a blank output when I run the two lines you mentioned, i.e., echo is waiting for messages to arrive. However, after I click on the button "Refresh list of topics publishing images" in the simulator GUI I start to see messages printed by the echo subscriber. Is this intended? If so, is it possible to get a camera to publish /camera_info immediately after the simulation starts?

**Comment by [AndrejOrsula](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/44778/andrejorsula/) on 2021-03-18**:
I do not believe this behaviour is intended, as sensors should publish data whenever simulation is running. Have you tried subscribing to the topic programatically?

What's interesting is that when I run the example locally, I get the messages immediately. However, I am able to reproduce your issue when I run the same commands using one of my Docker images. The main difference is that locally I build Ignition from source but install Debian package inside Docker.

**Comment by [AndrejOrsula](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/44778/andrejorsula/) on 2021-03-18**:
As a workaround, you can add `<topic>camera</topic>` under the `ImageDisplay` GUI plugin inside SDF and that seems to make it publish immediately.

Don't ask my why, I have no logical explanation. :D Maybe someone who worked on it has an idea.

**Comment by [FirefoxMetzger](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/44219/firefoxmetzger/) on 2021-03-18**:
Sounds a bit like a bug that has been fixed on master, but didn't propagate to the package archive yet. I've noticed this same behavior when subscribing to topics from python [[tracking issue](https://github.com/ignitionrobotics/ign-transport/issues/225)]. There is something funny about tracking subscribers in ign-transport. Another workaround is to additional subscribe to `/camera` via `ign -e -t /camera`, which then triggers publication of `/camera_info` as well. . .

**Comment by [Adwait](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/42410/adwait/) on 2021-04-18**:
Thanks @AndrejOrdula, I was facing the same issue with my rover world. I was trying to retrieve the image taken by the sensor.